# Leave out the sugar in a Belgian tripel?

Tags: sugar, belgian

It seems like the only reason to add plain sugar is to boost ABV without changing flavor. If I want a lighter beer, can I just leave out the sugar? Or will that affect the flavor?

I'm not talking about dark candi syrups or raw sugar like turbinado. I know they contribute unique flavors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alcohol itself adds to flavour/aroma, and to perception of body, the latter being critical for tripel, characterized by its dryness.

So, the answer depends on what you mean by "lighter" here. If you mean just "less alcohol", then sure, leave out the sugar. If "lighter" is about compounded *perception* of lightness, then you may want to reduce grain, too. In any case, it won't be tripel anymore. If you're after a crisp light beer with a belgian twist, check out the sort called "trappist single".

Comment: "Brew like a monk": drinkability of a tripel is indeed created through the addition of sugar, up to 18% of the grain bill, high attenuation, which reduces the sweetness, and much carbonation too. Westmalle Tripel being the original example of the style.

Comment: That makes sense to me if you replace some of the malt with sugar to get a lower FG. The resulting beer would have a lighter body and the same ABV.

But if you have two recipes that are identical except that one has extra sugar added, would the increased ABV create a perception of lightness even though they both have the same FG?

Comment: @JoshYeager I'd still say yes, as alcohol counterbalances sweetness to some point. I wouldn't bet more than my lunch money on that, however, since I never made a clean split batch experiment. Sounds interesting though...

Comment: But alcohol is sweet, so you wouldn't have the same beer.  In short, no, a beer without sugar but with increased ABV won't be the same as one with sugar.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'm going to make a split batch so I can teach myself what sugar's effect tastes like. (-:

Comment: Patersbier is essentially a "single".

Comment: @Wyrmwood BJCP 2015 guidelines tell that trappist single is a rather modern invention than patersbier, but likely the former was inspired by the latter

Comment: Interesting. I did not realize the 2015 guidelines had added the single. The 2008 guidelines called it "Blond Trappist table beer" but it was only mentioned under the catch-all Belgian Specialty Ale. The original patersbier or lower gravity table beer was for the monk's consumption while it seems the Trappist Single is indeed a modern-day commercial offering. :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you leave it out, you will not have a tripel.  Even more than alcohol, the sugar is there for what's referred to as "digestibility".  It lightens the body of the beer.  If you leave it out you will be making a different style of beer.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Thanks, Denny. I still feel like I'm misunderstanding something. See my comment above. BTW, I love the podcast!